# Text is not displayed in chrome, but working in IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html-helper, display, dynamic-tables

I am trying to create a table dynamically in a web page and using ASP.NET to do so.

Below is the sample code I am using. The same code is working in IE, but not in Chrome.

```
trPropertyHeader.CssClass = "HeaderClass";
trPropertyHeader.Attributes.Add("onclick", "ExpandCollapseHeaders(this,true)");
TableCell tcTextDisplay = new TableCell();
tcTextDisplay.ColumnSpan = 3;
trPropertyHeader.Attributes.Add("DisplayText", "Header Text");
tcTextDisplay.Style.Add("cursor", "pointer");
```

**Header Text** should be displayed in the web page, instead it is empty.

Will there be any other attribute to be added to make the display text visible.

FYI, the text that is being displayed will be a used to expand and collapse the table.

Comment: Perhaps more useful to show the rendered HTML and CSS in a [mcve]??? Click edit and then `[<>]` snippet editor. Your code is not runnable in a browser

Comment: Do you get any errors?